# Email scope problem / email address isn't sent in /me request

Tags: php, email, scope, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using PHP SDK 3.1 and I have a problem with retrieving email from /me request. 
My scope looks like:

```
protected $scope = 'email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown';
```

and I'm getting url by:

```
$this->fb->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => $this->scope));
```

where $this->fb is an Facebook instance.

Problem is when i call

```
$userProfile = $this->fb->api('/me');
```

Variable $userProfile contains a lot of data but there is no email. Few days ago it worked but somehow it stopped.

What should i do to get email?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using same kit and the following, works just fine. `user_about_me` should not be necessary.

`$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(  array('scope' => 'user_about_me,email' ) );`

Nota : If you did not give the rights upfront, try re-authorizing the app for the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->fb->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email'))
```

should work but remember that you can only get the connected user email and not his friends emails